# Create XML from Treenode in Python or PHP

Tags: php, python, xml

i have a xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>client</title>
    <link>http://www.client.com</link>
    <description>gdfgdfgdg</description>
<item>
   <id>N10987281A</id>
    <title>dfgdfgdfgdfgdg  </title>
    <link>https://www.client.com/p</link>
    <image_link>https://client.com/t_desktop-pdp-v1/v1505732008/N10987281A_1.jpg</image_link>
    <condition>new</condition>
    <availability>in stock</availability>
    <price>31.50 AED</price>
    <gtin>27242852310</gtin>
    <brand>dfgdgdfg</brand>
    <mpn>CDR 50 Shrink</mpn>
    <custom_label_2>audio_video</custom_label_2>
    <description>fgdfgdfgdfg rgdfgdgdfgdfgdfgdg</description>
    <product_type>Electronics &amp; Mobiles/Television &amp; Video</product_type>
    <google_product_category>Electronics</google_product_category>
    <shipping>
        <price>0.00 AED</price>
        <country>AE</country>
        <service>Standard</service>
    </shipping>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

for the above XML, I have tree node like below and the tree node I'm getting from this [getTreenode of the xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532734/gettreenode-of-a-xml-in-python)

```
/rss    
/rss@version    2.0
/rss/channel    
/rss/channel/title  client
/rss/channel/link   http://www.client.com
/rss/channel/description    gdfgdfgdg
/rss/channel/item   
/rss/channel/item/id    N10987281A
/rss/channel/item/title dfgdfgdfgdfgdg
/rss/channel/item/link  https://www.client.com/p
/rss/channel/item/image_link    https://client.com/t_desktop-pdp-v1/v1505732008/N10987281A_1.jpg
/rss/channel/item/condition new
/rss/channel/item/availability  in stock
/rss/channel/item/price 31.50 AED
/rss/channel/item/gtin  27242852310
/rss/channel/item/brand dfgdgdfg
/rss/channel/item/mpn   CDR 50 Shrink
/rss/channel/item/custom_label_2    audio_video
/rss/channel/item/description   fgdfgdfgdfg rgdfgdgdfgdfgdfgdg
/rss/channel/item/product_type  Electronics & Mobiles/Television & Video
/rss/channel/item/google_product_category   Electronics
 /rss/channel/item/shipping 
 /rss/channel/item/shipping/price   0.00 AED
 /rss/channel/item/shipping/country AE
 /rss/channel/item/shipping/service Standard
```

Now how can I create an XML from the above tree node itself

Can someone help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the php tag relevant?

Comment: @NigelRen,  I want either in PHP or Python,

Comment: Anybody any help

Comment: One problem you will have is that the namespace is lost in the treenode listing - so trying to get back to `<g:id>` is impossible without other changes. (I'm not a python person).

Comment: I don't need a namespace, I don't need  nodes to be like in <g: id>, I just need it like <id>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added comments as it's easier than trying to add a full description.

But it's basically read the tree from a file, create or move to the levels as you parse each line.  If there is an `@` in the tag, then this means create an attribute...

```
$file = file("a.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
// Extract root node to create new document
$firstLine = array_shift($file);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<" . substr($firstLine,1) . " />");

foreach ( $file as $line ) {
    // Set start insert point to root node
    $xmlC = $xml;
    $matches = [];
    // Split into tag name and content parts
    preg_match("/(.*?)\s+(.*)/", $line, $matches);
    // Split levels of tag name apart
    $tag = explode("/", substr($matches[1], 1));
    // Root node is already there
    $roottag = array_shift($tag);
    // Check if adding an attribute to root node
    $element = explode("@", $roottag);
    if ( isset($element[1]) )   {
        $xmlC->addAttribute($element[1], $matches[2]);
        unset($matches[2]);
    }
    // For each level of tag
    foreach ( $tag as $level )  {
        $element = explode("@", $level);
        // If tag is already set, then just move down a level
        if ( isset($xmlC->{$element[0]}) ) {
            $xmlC = $xmlC->{$element[0]};
        }
        // If not set then add a new element
        else    {
            $xmlC = $xmlC->addChild($element[0]);
        }
        // If an attribute needs to be created
        if ( isset($element[1]) )   {
            $xmlC->addAttribute($element[1], $matches[2]);
            unset($matches[2]);
        }
    }
    // If there is a value, then add it to last node
    if ( isset($matches[2]) ) {
        $xmlC[0] = $matches[2];
    }
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

A slightly trimmer loop which uses regex to extract the attribute as well...

```
foreach ( $file as $line ) {
    // Set start insert point to root node
    $xmlC = $xml;
    $matches = [];
    // Split into tag name, attribute and content parts
    preg_match("/(.*?)(@.*?)?\s+(.*)/", $line, $matches);

    // Split levels of tag name apart
    $tag = explode("/", substr($matches[1], 1));
    // Root node is already there
    $roottag = array_shift($tag);
    // For each level of tag
    foreach ( $tag as $level )  {
        // If tag is already set, then just move down a level
        if ( isset($xmlC->{$level}) ) {
            $xmlC = $xmlC->{$level};
        }
        // If not set then add a new element
        else    {
            $xmlC = $xmlC->addChild($level);
        }
    }
    // If there is a value, then add it to last node (either as an attribute or text
    if ( !empty($matches[3]) ) {
        if ( !empty($matches[2]) )    {
            $xmlC->addAttribute(substr($matches[2],1), $matches[3]);
        }
        else    {
            $xmlC[0] = $matches[3];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try with this and see how it works and get back to you if need anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working perfectly. Thanks a lot once again